# Openpyxl load_workbook gives me KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, openpyxl

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and I'm trying to convert a file `.xlsx` into pandas DataFrame but `openpyxl` keeps giving me error.

My file's name is `Dry_Bean_Dataset.xlsx`, so what I'm doing is setting the path to that file and then creating the workbook with `openpyxl`. However, when I try the 'ws' function, it gives me KeyError.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
path2= 'C:/Users/nbravo/OneDrive - Schenck Process Group Holding/Documents/13. Master of Information Technology/2. Semestre 1 - 2021/Machine Learning/Lab02/DryBeanDataset/Dry_Bean_Dataset.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(path2)
ws = wb['Dry_Bean_Dataset']
```

And this is the error that I get:

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 ws = wb['Dry_Bean_Dataset']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py in __ getitem__(self, key)
271             if sheet.title == key:
272                 return sheet
--> 273         raise KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist.".format(key))
274
275     def __ delitem__(self, key):

KeyError: 'Worksheet Dry_Bean_Dataset does not exist.'

Comment: The exception is pretty clear: the worksheet "Dry_Bean_Dataset" isn't in the workbook. Check `wb.sheetnames`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Im really new to all this jupyter/python area. That really helped. Now I see where it was going wrong. Thanks!